# String output modifiers in Python

Tags: python

In C++, objects can be output by "left-shifting" them to `cout`. They can be preceded by modifiers that change the output:

```
// print 2 numbers 'a' and 'b' in 0xAAAABBBB (hex) format
cout << "0x" << hex << uppercase << setw(4) << setfill('0') << a
```

[(Source)](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/24976/)

I'm looking for something similar in Python: I have a class for which I want two different possible outputs: it's something containing a float which I want to output either as a normal float or as a fraction. Currently, I'm passing a `use_fractions` flag in the constructor and have an `if use_fractions: ... else: ...` conditional in the `__str__`  and `__repr__` members. But I find that logically flawed: the output format isn't some intrinsic property of the object, so I don't want to pass it to the constructor.

So my question is, is there any sort of modifier to `__str__` comparable to the C++ example above? Something like a "contextual" parameter that can be set, and whose state I can check within `__str__`?

Comment: [rjust()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rjust.htm)

Comment: So, would `a` be `0x0061`? eg: `'0x' + format(ord('a'), '04X')`

Comment: See the [string format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec)

Comment: @JonClements: you can tell `format()` to include the `0x` prefix, you know. :-) `format(ord('a'), '#06x')` (size adjusted to allow for the 2 characters used by the prefix).

Comment: @Martijn good call... I'd completely forgotten about `#` - have to make it `#06X` though....

Comment: @JonClements: unfortunately, it also uppercases the prefix then..

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `__format__`; the method called to handle the [formatting mini language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for a given type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, you'd use [string formatting with `str.format()` or `format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), which delegates handling of the actual formatting to a `.__format__()` special method.

The special method is passed the actual format spec; you can use anything you like there:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __format__(self, spec):
...         if spec == 'f':
...             return 'fractions used'
...         else:
...             return 'decimals used'
... 
>>> format(Foo(), 'f')
'fractions used'
>>> format(Foo(), 'g')
'decimals used'
```

The [`datetime.datetime()` type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) uses this to support full `strptime` formatting, for example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> format(datetime.now(), '%Y')
'2014'
```

Comment: You could add the examples `'{0}'.format(Foo())` and `'{0:f}'.format(Foo())`. The `format()` function isn't used very often as far as I can tell.

Comment: @BlackJack: `format()` should be used *far more often*; `str.format()` should only be used *when interpolating values into a larger string*. There is little point in parsing out the whole string format if all you are doing is formatting one value.

Comment: @MartinPieters: Converting just one object into a string without also adding other characters is quite rare in my experience.

Comment: @BlackJack: whenever you need to convert an integer value to hex or binary notation without a prefix, `format()` is your best option, for example.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
class StringState():
    fraction = False

class SetFraction():
    def __str__(self):
        StringState.fraction = True
        return ""

class UnsetFraction():
    def __str__(self):
        StringState.fraction = False
        return ""

class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0.05

    def __str__(self):
        if StringState.fraction:
            return "1/20"
        else:
            return "0.05"


print Test(),'\n',SetFraction(),Test(),'\n',UnsetFraction(),Test()
```

Output:

```
0.05
 1/20
 0.05
```

I don't think there's any way to attach state to print itself, but if you use your own separate class, and then reference it in your print statements, you can achieve the same effect. There's probably a way to avoid the ugly spaces too.

Comment: That's trying to press an C++ idiom into Python. And it's ugly, overly complex, and has a single global state for the `fraction` flag, i.e. it is not thread safe and not even reentrant.

Comment: I absolutely agree, but OP was looking for a way to use a C++ idiom in Python. This solution also addresses the "Something like a "contextual" parameter that can be set, and whose state I can check within __str__?"

Comment: The answer to that question would simply be _no_ because there is no way to pass in additional context to `__str__()` calls. That's what `__format__()` is for.

Comment: `__format__` is a better solution, no doubt (I'm quite pleased to have learned about it, in fact), but this solution does set a contextual parameter, and it is checked within `__str__`. It's not passed in to each `__str__` call, but it being persistent between calls could be considered a benefit.

Comment: It's still much too complex.  A `global` for the flag and functions for `SetFraction()` and `UnsetFraction()` would have been sufficient for the same effect. And as long as there are still extra spaces and the flag isn't associated with the file instead of _one_ global flag I wouldn't call it a solution, because it doesn't come close enough to C++ streams and formatting. If you want _that_ I would start with a `Stream` class that wraps a file object and formatting states, and implements the `<<` operator.